# Is it possible to show that $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{k^2}\right) = \frac{1}{2\pi}(e^\pi-e^{-\pi})$?

Tags: calculus, infinite-product

So I stumbled on this question by trying different infinite products on my calculator and trying to find interesting ones that do converge. I calculated this specific product to some larger n and found that it is equal (to enough decimal places to call it equal) to:

$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{k^2}\right) \approx 3.67607791... \approx \frac{1}{2\pi}(e^\pi-e^{-\pi})$$

I found this equality by searching the decimal number online, to my surprise I didn't find any mention of this product. I only got lucky and found this number as the result of the following integral:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^tdt$$

Now I tried showing that these are equal algebraically, however I failed spectacularly at that. Here is what I tried:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}(e^x-e^{-x})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{\pi}{n}\right)^n-\left(1-\frac{\pi}{n}\right)^n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+\pi)^n-(n-\pi)^n}{n^n}$$

This is where I stopped because I don't know what to do with this $(a+b)^n-(a-b)^n$ term or if this is even the right approach.

I also tried to write the initial product as:

$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{k^2}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^2+1}{k^2}=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(k+i)(k-i)}{k^2}$$

However contrary to my hopes I wasn't able to do anything with this, other than this I don't really know how to solve these infinite products.

Is it possible to show this equality and if so how?

<sub>PS: Sorry if this question is a duplicate, it does feel like it, but I did not find anything about this simple product anywhere.</sub>

Comment: Look for the Weierstrass product for sine function, $\sin z = z\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{(k\pi)^2}\right)$.

Comment: I see, for $z=i\pi$ this does in fact answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a standard infinite product representation for the sine function:
$$
\sin x = x\prod_{k \geq 1} \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{(\pi k)^2}\right).
$$
This holds for all $x \in \mathbf C$. Setting $x = i\pi$,
$$
\sin(i\pi) = i\pi \prod_{k \geq 1} \left(1 + \frac{1}{k^2}\right).
$$
From $\sin(t) = (e^{it} - e^{-it})/(2i)$, we get $\sin(i\pi)/(i\pi) = (e^{-\pi} - e^\pi)/(-2\pi) = (e^\pi - e^{-\pi})/(2\pi)$.

Comment: I was not aware of this representation of sine, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Surprised that this reprentation is for $sin(x)$ not for $sinh(x)$. http://specialfunctionswiki.org/index.php/Weierstrass_factorization_of_sinh

Comment: @NoChance those functions are closely related: $\sinh(x) = (e^x-e^{-x})/2$, so $\sin(ix) = i\sinh(x)$.

Comment: True, thanks for the reply.